# Why does MiKTeX have old version of The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List?

Tags: symbols, packages, miktex, updating, ctan

On CTAN, the package named ["Comprehensive"](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive) contains a version of The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List dated **09 November 2009**.  But the [corresponding package on MiKTeX](http://www.miktex.org/packages/comprehensive) contains a version of the file from **3 January 2008**.  Why doesn't MiKTeX reflect the latest version on CTAN?  Can this be fixed?

Comment: This could just be the package as it is distributed with the MiKTeX (2.9). When you issue `texdoc symbols`, what version do you end up with? The same

Comment: @Werner: In MiKTeX I have the version with release date `3 January 2008`, where I read “This document lists 4947 symbols”. In my portable TeX Live I have a version from `9 November 2009`, where I can read “This document lists 5913 symbols”. In the latter the TOC has links, in the former not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first question can only be answered by the MiKTeX maintainer Christian Schenk. You could report this issue on the [MiKTeX Bug Tracker](http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/), which should answer your second question.